# How to cite an article that was re-edited later in an anthology

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I current have in ad hoc form the following article to cite

```
FRIEDMAN, Milton “The methodology of positive economics” (1953) in: HAUSMAN, Daniel M. (Ed.). The philosophy of economics: an anthology. Cambridge University Press, 1994.
```

What this means is that the original article was published in 1953, but I'm citing the version published in the anthology compiled by Hausman in 1994. Since I don't have access to the original paper in its original context, I wouldn't like to insinuate a deeper level of scholarship in that direction; at the same time it's important to the narrative/argument that this is an old article.

What's canonical BibTeX for this situation?

Comment: `biblatex` has a `related` feature that could be used here. Your average BibTeX style does not support that and so you probably have to put the information in the `note` field there.

Comment: I think a "note" field is probably fine for this, though: it really *is* a note, not bibliographical information as such. You are citing the 1994 revised paper, so adding a note "revised version of paper originally published in 1953" is quite appropriate IMO.